# Using Selenium to get the information within title= ' '

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

please help me to find the solution to get the information from this html code by using Selenium without XPath because I want to make a loop from it.

I want to get the result as: "4.7" from this "title="4.7/5 - 10378 Reviews"

please check the picture below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxa7n.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `driver` setup already,

Than try something like this,

```
rating = driver.find_element_by_class_name("stars").get_attribute("title")

print (rating)
```